# Manually adding suffixes to the legend ticks in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I manually add an arbitrary suffix to the legend ticks in ggplot?

For example, can I add something to the below code to generate the below plot with those unique legend ticks?

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

**Note that I manually added "(s)" to the end of the legend ticks using Photoshop.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use the `labels` argument in `scale_color_discrete`. This can take an `rlang` style lambda function that pastes an "(S)" at the end.

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_discrete(labels = ~paste(.x, "(S)"))
```

[image]